# Undo Redo stack is different in case of code mirror

Tags: codemirror, codemirror-modes, ui-codemirror

The stack for undo redo shall be maintained for every delimiter and pause in getting the keyboard buffer.

Is there a way to configure code mirror undo redo behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same can be configured using [historyEventDelay](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#option_historyEventDelay) option in code mirror